# What are the other Theravada Councils held between the 4th and 6th

Tags: history

[The Wikipedia entry on the 5th council](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fifth_Buddhist_council) says:

> However, there were a number of other councils held in Ceylon and Thailand between the fourth and sixth ...

What are these other councils? Where where they held? What was their significance?

Comment: I suggest you ask for citation there. Or initiate a discussion under the Talk tab.

Answer (score 1):

What are these other councils? Where were they held? What was their significance?

I am going to try to answer this to the best of my abilities.

I do not know the specifics of where they were held, but I do know what they are & their significance.

All the Buddhist councils are meant to preserve the Dhamma the Buddha formulated & to discuss the Tipitaka & its interpretations.

Buddhist councils have not consisted of all schools unified, although in some cases they have been.

I hope my answer suits you well! :)

May you be well.

Answer (score -1):

Councils are only held after some schism between the schools. Bah.

Politics is a Mara to arouse emotion; stick to all the precepts oneself... do not worry about; Titles, Recognition and other such nonsense.

Emotion is human delusion... Born out of: The feeling and sensation skandhas. There is only pain or not pain; same as pranayama breath; Only you know if the breath is a long pain or a short pain, not a long pain or not a short pain.

Move from such pranayama and it becomes the breath of; The Prajna Paramita: One of peace and wisdom.

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question -- please see [Answers vs Advice](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/61/254). If you don't think the question is worth answering then just don't answer it, or find a different question that is worth answering.

Comment: It was worth answering; and I did so with the proper practice... wearing white robes from causing or re-arousing schism isn't cool. OP if you really want to  know: email or call: Wat Carolina; The Abbot: Chao Kun was most likely at all of those councils he should be able to clarify when and what was said at them.

Answer (score -2):

Here is a descriptions of some of the councils and their significance
http://en.citizendium.org/wiki/Buddhist_councils

Comment: Please avoid posting link answers. The question should be addressed in the answer itself.

Comment: There's a Wikipedia article too, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddhist_councils

Comment: The Wikipedia article mostly agrees with your second link i.e. http://en.citizendium.org/wiki/Buddhist_councils ... but your first link i.e. http://www.thisismyanmar.com/nibbana/2589year.htm currently returns nothing (an 'empty' page) when I try it.